# How to overload getter functions without adding/ removing `const`ness of mem function?

Tags: c++, overloading, c++17, member-functions

I could not figure this out, why C++ is not allowing overloading according to the return type as in the following case
the three member(getter) function has different function signature and even when to store
the pointer to the member function we need different mem-function pointer types like:

```
for instance T = std::string
using constRefPtr   = const std::string&(MyStruct::*)() const;
using constValuePtr = const std::string(MyStruct::*)() const;
using valuePtr      = std::string(MyStruct::*)() const;
```

I have read this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267328/overload-class-function-operator-twice-as-setter-and-getter), where it was suggestion to have const and non-cost
member functions.

Question: How could I make the following (getter)overloads work without removing `const`ness
of each member functions(if it is possible through standard C++)?

I am using C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T> class MyStruct
{
    T m_val;
public: 
    explicit MyStruct(const T& value) 
        : m_val(value)
    {}
    const T& getVal() const {   return m_val; } // get val as const ref(no copy of member)
    const T getVal() const  {   return m_val; } // get a const member as return
    T getVal() const        {   return m_val; } // get a copy of member
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<std::string> obj{"string"};
    const auto& val_const_ref = obj.getVal();  // overload const std::string& getVal() const
    const auto val_const = obj.getVal();       // overload const std::string getVal()  const
    auto val = obj.getVal();                   // overload std::string getVal()  const
    return 0;
}
```

error messages I have got:

```
error C2373 : 'MyStruct<T>::getVal' : redefinition; different type modifiers
note: see declaration of 'MyStruct<T>::getVal'
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MyStruct<T>' being compiled
error C2059 : syntax error : 'return'
error C2238 : unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2143 : syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2556 : 'const T MyStruct<T>::getVal(void) const' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'const T &MyStruct<T>::getVal(void) const'
1 > with
1 > [
    1 > T = std::string
        1 > ]
    1 > C:\Z Drive\CPP Programs\Visual Studio Project\Main.cc(62) : note: see declaration of 'MyStruct<std::string>::getVal'
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MyStruct<std::string>' being compiled
error C2373 : 'MyStruct<std::string>::getVal' : redefinition; different type modifiers
note: see declaration of 'MyStruct<std::string>::getVal'
error C2059 : syntax error : 'return'
error C2238 : unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2146 : syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'T'
error C2530 : 'val_const_ref' : references must be initialized
error C2789 : 'val_const' : an object of const - qualified type must be initialized
note: see declaration of 'val_const'
```

Comment: "*the three member(getter) function has different function signature*" Except that they don't. Return type is not a part of the signature. See [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: What difference do you expect with `T` vs `const T` as a return type?

Comment: Why do you feel you need three flavors of `getVal` in the first place? I believe the first one - the one returning `const T&` - is quite sufficient; you should be able to use it everywhere you think you need the other two.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's sad that, C++ has such a decision. The link was helpful.

Comment: @Const no it is not, making result part of signature will create more problems that it would solve (if any).

Comment: `why C++ is not allowing overloading according to the return type` because this is written in C++ standard.

Comment: @SergeyA *because this is written in C++ standard* That's kind of escaping from the reason. I believe there is a reason why the standard community decided to put so.

Comment: *difference do you expect with T vs const T*: was thinking the way of calling it: `auto val = ` and `const auto val_const=` as explained/ commented in the code.

Comment: @Const first and foremost you have 2 versions of `foobar()` that are different by result type and one calls them like this `foobar();` (ignoring the result), which one should be called?

Comment: @Const ok lets start with basics `auto i = 5;` does the fact that `5` is constant affects  constness of `i`?

Comment: @Slava That makes sense. `i` could have `const` and `non-const` integers. Sorry. I misunderstood the case.

Comment: @Const I am afraid you still do not understand properly. When you do `auto i = whatever;` you make a copy of `whatever`. The fact that original of copy is `const` or not does not matter in this case. It is your choice to make `i` const or not. It is your copy you can do whatever with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You cannot overload on return type. Overload resolution takes into account the function signature. A function signature is made up of:

- function name
- cv-qualifiers
- parameter types

The standard says:

**1.3.11 signature**

> the information about a function that participates in overload
>   resolution (13.3): its parameter-type-list (8.3.5) and, if the
>   function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function
>   itself and the class in which the member function is declared. [...]

(Lightly edited from [Luchian Grigore's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568890/309334))

Answer (score 5):

You just... can't overload on return type, full stop.

You could just make two differently named functions:

```
T const& ref() const { return m_val; }
T val() const        { return m_val; }
```

Which *themselves* could be overloaded based on `const`ness or `&`ness:

```
T const& ref() const { return m_val; }
T&       ref()       { return m_val; }

T val() const&       { return m_val; }
T val() &&           { return std::move(m_val); }
```

Comment: What do the second overloads stand for? specifically `&&` and `const&`?

Comment: They're called [ref-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions).

Comment: Can you add example of code showing difference btw `val()`s? I think that would be helpful

Comment: Or may be do not have trivial getters/setters? Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

> Question: How could I make the following (getter)overloads work without removing constness of each member functions(if it is possible through standard C++)?

Name them appropriately. And as @Slava points out, when return a copied value there no point in distinguishing between `T` and `const T`, so something like:

```
const T& getConstRefVal() const { return m_val; } // get val as const ref(no copy of member)
T        getVal()         const { return m_val; } // get a copy of member
```

Comment: I think part of your question should be explanation that OP does not need that variations.